# Laravel task schedule call from a PHP file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am looking to set up a task schedule at infomaniak, unfortunately infomaniak does not accept php command but, just run a PHP file which in turn calls the shell command or a .sh script.

So how to perform artisan outside the laravel or from a php file as required infomaniak and ovh

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can call Artisan commands with the help of the `Artisan` Facade.
You can call a command by doing

```
Artisan::call($command, $options);
```

The Artisan Facade calls the underlying Console contract, so for more details see
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades#facade-class-reference and 
https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Contracts/Console/Kernel.html#method_call